# specifying relative directory in css

Tags: css

I'm having trouble specifying the directory to image files in a css style sheet.

the style sheets are in root/css/ and the image files are in root/image, when I want to reference lets say root/image/logo.gif in root/css/style.css I use url(../images/logo.gif).  However this doesn't work.  when I put the image files in the same directory as the css sheets and just reference them with url(logo.gif) it works.  If someone can let me know why the directory is not being referenced properly? (I believe ../takes you up one level no?)

thanks!

Comment: the images dir and css dir are in the same level, why would I go up twice?

Answer (score 1):

You have an 'image' folder but you are referring to it as 'images' in your CSS.